# Create Chart of 2 temp readings from firebase to Google charts

Tags: json, firebase, google-visualization

I have 2 tempsensors that send their temp every ten min to firebase.
My firebase is structured like this:

```
{
AB: {
     -K9kbKg4iqzaGP_mbKIC: {
     date: "05 Feb 2016 08:47:27 +0000",
     value: "013.2"
     },
    BattLevel: {}
},
AC: {
     -K9kaqlycXMDbH-LpVrH: {
     date: "05 Feb 2016 08:45:19 +0000",
     value: "009.4"
     },
     BattLevel: {}
     }
}
```

I would like to create a Google chart

But i don't seem to get the Json parsing wright.
I can add the temp of 1 sensor to display if i set the json path to
https://tempraspberry.firebaseio. com/AB.json

```
 /<script>

    // onload callback
    function drawChart() {

        // JSONP request
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: 'https://tempraspberry.firebaseio.com/AB.json',
            data: {page: 1},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
        }).done(function (results) {

            var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data1.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
            data1.addColumn('number', 'Temp');

            $.each(results, function (i, row) {
                data1.addRow([
                    (new Date(row.date)),
                    parseFloat(row.value)
                ]);
            });

           //tweede chart

            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: 'https://tempraspberry.firebaseio.com/AC.json',
                data: {page: 1},
                dataType: 'jsonp',
            }).done(function (results) {

                var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                data2.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
                data2.addColumn('number', 'Temp');

                $.each(results, function (i, row) {
                    data2.addRow([
                        (new Date(row.date)),
                        parseFloat(row.value)
                    ]);
                });

            });
            //einde tweede chart
        });
        var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
        chart.draw(joinedData, {
            height: 300,
            width: 600,
            interpolateNulls: true
        });
    }

    // load chart lib
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['corechart']
    });

    // call drawChart once google charts is loaded
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

</script>
```

I get can't find variable data1 with the above code.

Comment: You title says "Highcharts", but in fact you are using google charts. Please, update title or your code and tags.

Comment: I'm sorry had the wrong code pasted in. Now is the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a scope issue, declare the `DataTable` up front, something like this...

```
function drawChart() {
  var data;
  var sensors;

  sensors = ['AB', 'AC'];
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Temp');

  // start process
  requestData();

  function requestData() {
    var nextSensor;

    if (sensors.length > 0) {
      nextSensor = sensors.pop();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://tempraspberry.firebaseio.com/' + nextSensor + '.json',
        data: {page: 1},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
      }).done(loadData);
    } else {
      loadChart();
    }
  }

  function loadData(results) {
    $.each(results, function (i, row) {
      data.addRow([
        (new Date(row.date)),
        parseFloat(row.value)
      ]);
    });
    requestData();
  }

  function loadChart() {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      height: 300,
      width: 600,
      interpolateNulls: true
    });
  }
}

google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Comment: The above code works thanks, the only problem is that it puts the results of AB and AC in the same datatable. I should get a datatable data1 and data2.  Thanks for the working example. Going to try to change it so that data1 and data2 are filled.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks with small adjustments it works now.
I now have 2 datatables that show on one Google Chart.
I know the code probably isn't pretty but it works :-)

```
<script>

function drawChart() {
    var data1;
    var data2;
    var sensors;

    sensors = ['AB', 'AC'];

    data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data1.addColumn('date', 'Tijd');
    data1.addColumn('number', 'Paleis Zora');
    data2.addColumn('date', 'Tijd');
    data2.addColumn('number', 'Buiten');

    // start process
    requestData();

    function requestData() {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://tempraspberry.firebaseio.com/AB.json',
                data: {page: 1},
                dataType: 'jsonp',
            }).done(loadData);
        }

    //eerste datatable
    function loadData(results) {
        $.each(results, function (i, row) {
            data1.addRow([
                (new Date(row.date)),
                parseFloat(row.value)
            ]);
        });
        requestData2();
    }
    //tweededatatable
    function requestData2() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://tempraspberry.firebaseio.com/AC.json',
            data: {page: 1},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
        }).done(loadData2);
    }

    //eerste datatable
    function loadData2(results) {
        $.each(results, function (i, row) {
            data2.addRow([
                (new Date(row.date)),
                parseFloat(row.value)
            ]);
        });
        loadChart();
    }



    function loadChart() {
        var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
        chart.draw(joinedData, {
            height: 500,
            width: 800,
            interpolateNulls: true
        });
    }

}



google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```